# Issues with long lineages (DAG) in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, directed-acyclic-graphs

We usually use Spark as processing engines for data stored on S3 or HDFS. We use Databricks and EMR platforms. 
 One of the issues I frequently face is when the task size grows, the job performance is degraded severely. For example, let's say I read data from five tables with different levels of transformation like (filtering, exploding, joins, etc), union subset of data from these transformations, then do further processing (ex. remove some rows based on a criteria that requires windowing functions etc) and then some other processing stages and finally save the final output to a destination s3 path. If we run this job without it takes very long time. However, if we save(stage) temporary intermediate dataframes to S3 and use this saved (on S3) dataframe for the next steps of queries, the job finishes faster. Does anyone have similar experience? Is there a better way to handle this kind of long tasks lineages other than checkpointing?

What is even more strange  is for longer lineages spark throws an expected error like column not found, while the same code works if intermediate results are temporarily staged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the intermediate data by saving the dataframe, or using a checkpoint is the only way to fix it.  You're probably running into an issue where the optimizer is taking a really long time to generate the plan.  The quickest/most efficient way to fix this is to use localCheckpoint.  This materializes a checkpoint locally.

```
val df = df.localCheckpoint()
```